# Ускорить selenium webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-3.6

В моём проекте необходимо делать скриншот области страницы, я нашёл selenium wd, но он очень долго запускается, что может быть проблемой при использовании. Я думаю, что дело в том, что он создаёт при запуске инстанс хедлесс хрома, можно ли это делать до использования метода get()?
Стоит учесть и то, что это всё должно работать при нескольких параллельных запросах. Я думаю, что можно создать пул из `chromedriver`, например, из 5и, а потом запускать их по-очереди. Но я не знаю, как это сделать
Код:

```
def get():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_driver = "/mnt/e/pibot/old/chromedriver"

    brw = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
    try:
        brw.get('https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0')
        brw.set_window_size(1280, 5000)

        # правильная обрезка скрина
        try:
            location_toc = brw.find_element_by_id('toc').location
            print(brw.find_element_by_id('toc').text)
        except:
            location_toc = {'x': 0, 'y': 500}
        print(location_toc)

        location_content = brw.find_element_by_id('content').location
        size_content = brw.find_element_by_id('content').size
        brw.save_screenshot('/mnt/e/pibot/old/'+r+'a.png')

        im = Image.open('/mnt/e/pibot/old/'+r+'a.png')
        im = im.crop((location_content['x'], location_content['y'],
                      location_content['x'] + size_content['width'], location_content['y'] + location_toc['y']-85))
        im.save('/mnt/e/pibot/old/'+r+'a.png')
        print('Готово, выход')
        print(brw.current_url)
    except:
        raise Exception
    finally:
        brw.close()
```

Comment: измерения показали, что строчка `webdriver.Chrome()` у вас наибольшее время занимает? Если да, руками service запустите и с помощью Remote к нему подключайтесь.

Comment: Я просто не знаю, сколько таких сервисов могу поднять? И как лучше всего реализовать "занятость" и "свободность" каждого из сервисов

Comment: цифры добавьте, которые показывают, что сколько времени у вас занимает и сколько хотите чтобы занимало.